# Why ng-repeat-start and ng-repear-end not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to build a simple comment app with Angular JS (also using Laravel), and here is a code:

```
<div ng-controller="CommentController">
    <div ng-repeat-start="comment in comments" class="comment">
        <h3>Comment {{ comment.id }} <small>by {{ comment.author }}</small></h3>
        <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here my JS file:

```
function CommentController($scope) {
    $scope.comments = [
        { id: 1 },
        { author: "Artem" },
        { text: "Angular comment" }
    ];
}
```

And this is the output:

## Comment 1 by

## Comment by Artem

## Comment by

Angular comment

Im using AngularJS 1.2.22, if this can help you.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end in this case? Won't simple ng-repeat on one div be sufficient?

Comment: First I used ng-repeat, same problem.

Comment: what r u trying to achieve

Comment: just like Mat answered, your JSON/model is formatted incorrectly or is missing some properties. You can use a simple `ng-repeat` for that too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON object is in wrong format probably.

From what your are trying to achieve it should be in the below format:

```
$scope.comments = [
    { id: 1, author: "Artem", text: "Angular comment" },
    { id: 2, author: "Other", text: "Other Angular comment" }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller doesn't seem to be registered. You should do something like:

```
myApp.controller('CommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.comments = [
        { id: 1, author: "Artem", text: "Angular comment" },
        { id: 2, author: "Other", text: "Other Angular comment" }
    ];
}]);
```

Only change **myApp** to your module name.

Answer (score 0):

1.Here no need of ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end directives. Any special reason behind those directives?.

2.can achieve this by using just ng-repeat.

if you want to use these two directives. try this

```
<div ng-controller="CommentController">
    <div ng-repeat-start="comment in comments" class="comment">
        <h3>Comment {{ comment.id }} <small>by {{ comment.author }}</small></h3>

    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end></div>
          <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

OR, simple way is:

```
 <div ng-controller="CommentController">
        <div ng-repeat="comment in comments" class="comment">
            <h3>Comment {{ comment.id }} <small>by {{ comment.author }}</small></h3>
             <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Angular DOC](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

3.your `JSON` format also might be wrong. angular treats each value as object. If you want to make `object` with three values change your `JSON` like this.

```
function CommentController($scope) {
    $scope.comments = [
        { id: 1 ,
         author: "Artem",
         text: "Angular comment" }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What @zorza mentioned might also be correct.

Unless somewhere below in your code you have used something like below:

```
myApp.controller('CommentController', 'CommentController');
```